# How to get first column td value from prime ng table in angular 7

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular5, angular7

Tried to get first column table td value when click on the first td of each tr.I tried but not working I know how to write in jquery but i do not know how to write in angular 7.If anyone know please help me to find the solution.

```
<p-table id="dt" [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" [scrollable]="true" [rows]="10"  [virtualRowHeight]="30" [loading]="loading"
    [virtualScroll]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadCarsLazy($event)" [lazy]="true" [totalRecords]="totalRecords">

    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of cols">
                {{col.header}} 
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr style="height:30px">
            <td *ngFor="let col of cols">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-table-primeng-v6-t1k6ng?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You should wrap your `td` in `ng-container` so that you could add click event to the `td`.
2. Move `*ngFor` to the `ng-container`.
3. Add click event handler to the 'td' and pass the number of the column (index of the loop) to it.

template should be updated like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let col of cols; let i = index;">
  <td (click)="handleClick(i)">
     {{rowData[col.field]}} 
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

If it's index is zero, then execute functionality you want.

Component should be updated like this:

```
handleClick(numberOfCol: number) {
  if(numberOfCol === 0) {
     console.log('First column clicked');
  }
}
```

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-table-primeng-v6-admpwx

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click event on the first column:

```
  <td (click)="doSomething(rowData)">{{ rowData['vin'] }}</td>
```

and

```
  doSomething(row) {
    this.cellClicked = row["vin"];
  }
```

See working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-table-primeng-v6-qlyf5p?file=src/app/app.component.html)